# Why I need to explicitly specify credentials for remote PowerShell execution

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, powershell-remoting, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I created a VSTS task **PowerShell on Target Machines** which executes a power shell on remote machine. This task is created as a part of release definition.

Logically speaking when I trigger a new release then build agent executes this power shell on remote machine. Let's say target machine is M1 & my build agent is running under a user account u1. I made u1 as administrator on M1.

If the account under which service agent is running is an administrator on target machine, then why do I need to explicitly mention the credentials again. If I do not specify the credentials, then it throw error.

Logically speaking when build agent execute any task then it would have the same identify under which build agent service is running. If that application is an administrator on target machine, then why do I need to pass credentials explicitly. Should it internally pass the identity.

Atul Sureka

Atul

Comment: How about if you "run as administrator" on the remote machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it isn’t use the current user (build agent running account) for Resource UserName (uses Admin username) and it fails before deploying machine.

In other words, the check Resource Username action will be passed (will be failed if don’t specify the admin username) if you specify any user for Resource Username (Admin login name) even through the user isn’t existing in target machine. (You can set system.debug to true, then queue builds and compare the log)

I submit a user voice here: [VSTS build PowerShell on target machine default user](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/31232884-vsts-build-powershell-on-target-machine-default-us), that you can vote.